# Where does Rav Dessler mention that root word of אהבה is הב?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, jewish-books, love

I read in one of Rav Dessler's books where he says that the root word of אהבה is הב, which means "give" in Aramaic.

Does anyone know where he mentions this?

Comment: Isn't this a gemara

Comment: @Sam, I believe it is Rav Dessler's innovation.

Comment: It makes much sense. In Judaism, love is about giving, not getting as it is *lehavdil* in the secular world.

Comment: Rav Hirsch, breshis 22:2
אשר אהבת - **מלשון הב**, דהיינו לתת ולהתמסר לזולת, וגם לראות שהזולת יתחבר אליו, I think all Rav Hirsch is saying is that giving is indicative of love, and that if you love someone, you give them things to ensure that they will love you back. It's a little less romantic than the way Rav Dessler allegedly explained.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Dessler, I believe, writes this in מכתב מאליהו  חלק א קונטרוס החסד

After a quick perusal I did not find it there. However, others cite it from that source, as well. See [here](http://www.orot.ac.il/publications/meorot/Pages/5772s-shma1.aspx) and [here](http://www.aish.co.il/sp/pg/211692541.html)

Comment: Can you please send me a link to this sefer?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I can't find any online ... the copyright expires 2024 or so

Comment: Do you know where he says this in his kuntress?

Comment: An excerpt is cited here:http://www.aspaklaria.info/001_ALEF/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%94.htm

Comment: @Yoni did you quickly peruse part ב of kuntress hachesed?  Could be there.

Comment: @YeZ Thanks..I was up to that...Maybe tomorrow I'll have time for that...

Comment: @Yoni: Check מכתב מאליהו חלק א קונטרוס החסד, pages 32-51 and 140-145.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - well if you have the text, you can find it, too!

Comment: @Yoni: I don't have the text.

Comment: See [here](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/chavero/28chavero.htm) (paragraph titled "Two Sides of the Same Coin").

Answer (score 2):

Rav Eliyahu Dessler (*Michtav Me’Eliyahu* Volume 1, *Kuntres HaChesed*, pages 35-38) says, *“Every positive emotion stems from giving and flows outward from us to others, whereas every negative emotion revolves around taking for selfish motives.” Indeed, the root of the Hebrew word for אהבה, love, is הב, to give. In other words, “Giving leads to Love."*